# InDesign: How to move a paragraph up or down without baseline shift?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph

I would like to know how I can change the vertical position of a paragraph in the text without using the baseline shift.

I basically would like to do exactly what "space before" and "space after" from the paragraph style settings do, just with a *negative* value. My goal basically is to have two consecutive paragraphs overlap.

I would like to a achieve an effect similar to this example:
[image]

As you can see, the date kind of looks like it's hanging down from the heading, and the text is next to it. Now my idea was to create a paragraph style for the text and a paragraph style for the consecutive text. Then I wanted to either let the date have a negative "space after" or let the text have a negative "space before". However, that's not possible. I can only set positive values. Another possible way I've found is applying a baseline shift to the text, but that doesn't seem like a clean solution to me.

Comment: I would just use an anchored object for that, to get the black box and the spacing right. I don’t think there is a way to move a regular paragraph up or down apart from the baseline shift. I don’t see why baseline shift wouldn’t work for the actual vertical movement, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **Nested Line Style** *for 1 line* to the gray paragraph style (the consecutive text), with a 0 leading character style:

[image: paragraph style]

[image: text]